# Why the retrieved result set string doesn't work with the .equals()

Tags: java, mysql

I'm retrieving some information from a database and I want to check if the value is null. Although the string retrieved from the database is "null" the equals() returns false.

I tried trim(), just in case there were any spaces in the retrieved string

```
     String code = product.retrieveCode();
            System.out.println("the code is :"+ code);

            if (code.equals("null")==true){  
                // do this 
            }
            else{
                //   do that
            }
```

Please let it be noted that the database doesn't have any data stored.

Comment: You can remove the ==true sine equals retrns a boolean.

Comment: Are you sure it returns the String "null" (as opposed to `null` reference)?

Comment: yes on the retrieveCode method I return rs.getString

Comment: Use a debugger and inspect the *actual* value of `code`. You're the only with access to this information.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart true but I need to know if it's true of false

Comment: If it’s false it returns false. If it’s true it’s true. There’s no need for a redundant check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by 'Eran', the value in `code` is probably a `null` reference. Do,

`if (code == null)`

instead of

`if (code.equals("null")==true)`

This likely occurs because the `rs` object returns `null` when you call it's `getString()` method. `ResultSet` will return `null` when the column value is SQL NULL. ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)))

Comment: Although what I said is true, since I didn't have anything to lose I tried your and Eran's  suggestion and it worked. Still curious why this happens though.

Comment: @Volpym So, I guess you're using ResultSet, if the column value in SQL is null, then `getString` returns null ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int))). The `println` internally calls `toString` on the object converting the null value, into a "null" string.

Answer (score 1):

your logic and syntax is correct.In this case here your database value is probably assigning null value to code and you are checking whether a string of "null" is equal to code. This will give error as it is null reference. Make sure that you are getting a "null" else if its empty just check equals case withe whitespace

Answer (score 0):

It prints Yes. so I don't think java doing anything wrong

```
String code = "null";
if (code.equals("null")){  
     System.out.println("Yes");
} else{
   //   do that
}
```

I think it is a null reference. Please do the below code.

```
if (code==null){  
   System.out.println("Yes");
} else{
       //   do that
}
```

Comment: Looks like you and the others are correct. Trying to figure our why this is the case.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of debugging code

Comment: there is no need to. Chrisvin pointed me to oracle's docs and I got my answer. Thank you for you time and help